# Update Query for multivalue fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010 I have a multivalue field containing values of A,B,C and D with primary IDs of 1,2,3 and 4 in that order.

If I was to run the following SQL:

```
UPDATE Table
Set Table.Multivalue.Value = 1
WHERE Field 1 = "True" AND Field 2 = "True";
```

Then run

```
UPDATE Table
Set Table.Multivalue.Value = 2
WHERE Field 1 = "True" AND Field 2 = "True";
```

Will I have a Multivalue field as A,B or just B? I would like it to be A,B but I have my doubts as to whether this would work. If it won't work could someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: The right direction to solving this problem is to normalize your database.  Step 1 is to go into access, press function key F1, type normalize into the textbox, and press enter.

Comment: What happened when you tried the above queries yourself?